# Android 8.1 Fragment setExitTransition bug

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, android-8.1-oreo

I am using this code for fragment transitions:

```
Transition transition = new Fade();
transition.addTarget(recyclerView);
setExitTransition(transition);
```

But now when i run this code on Android 8.1 api 27, the view is removed and doesnt come visible after return to fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In 27 API was changed method `TransitionUtils.createViewBitmap`, now it also add `View` in `ViewGroupOverlay`, that entails removing view from hierarchy `View` of previous `Scene`. How result this to cause side-effects, because this method designed to bypass the removing `View`.

In the documentation says, what `View` can be removed from parent only in case if `Scene` was created from a layout resource file.

More detail [Visibility.onDisappear](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Visibility.html#onDisappear(android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.transition.TransitionValues,%20int,%20android.transition.TransitionValues,%20int))

Try to use this:

```
@TargetApi(19)
public class FadeSafeOreo extends Fade {

    public FadeSafeOreo() {
        super();
    }

    public FadeSafeOreo(int fadingMode) {
        super(fadingMode);
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public FadeSafeOreo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public Animator onDisappear(ViewGroup sceneRoot, TransitionValues startValues, int startVisibility, TransitionValues endValues, int endVisibility) {
        RemovedView removedView = null;
        boolean existStart = startValues != null && startValues.view != null;
        boolean existEnd = endValues != null && endValues.view != null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27 && !canRemoveViews() && existStart && !existEnd) {
            removedView = new RemovedView(startValues.view);
        }
        Animator animator = super.onDisappear(sceneRoot, startValues, startVisibility, endValues, endVisibility);
        if (removedView != null) removedView.append();
        return animator;
    }

    private static class RemovedView {
        private View view;
        private ViewGroup parent;
        private int position = -1;

        private RemovedView(View view) {
            this.view = view;

            if (view != null && view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup) {
                parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                for (int i = 0, count = parent.getChildCount(); i < count; i++) {
                    if (parent.getChildAt(i) == view) {
                        position = i;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void append() {
            if (view != null) {
                if (parent != null) {
                    if (view.getParent() != parent && position >= 0) {
                        parent.addView(view, position);
                    }
                    parent = null;
                }
                view = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```